# meaning of the expression "I have dreamed you something"

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

The expression is from the Rolling Stones' song Wild Horses.

> I know I dreamed you a sin and a lie

What does it mean?

Would it be "I dreamed FOR you a sin and a lie"? As if the speaker made bad plans for the woman he is singing to? I can't see another possible meaning for this weird expression.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about interpreting rock song lyrics.

Comment: so it's not english I guess...

Comment: Lyrics of rock songs don't have to 'mean' anything. It could mean he dreamed _that the other person was_ 'a sin and a lie'. Or that his being with them was that? Who knows? Nobody. It is fairly certain to be something bad, because sins and lies are bad.

Comment: hellofriends, in English, songs can just be words made to fit a a tune, perhaps intended to suggest a feeling, or to be a puzzle or an enigma. Likewise with poems.

Comment: Also often providing a rhyme is important. Maybe they sat and went 'baby don't cry',  'fly in the sky', 'my dog's gonna die', 'oh me oh my!', 'a sin and a lie'... Hey! That's the one!

Comment: Hellofriends - Of course it's English, it just doesn't convey any clear meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use **dream** in ways it is not normally used and still be understood, in a sense, but only if the pattern of the sentence makes clear that the verb **dream** is being substituted for a verb that does make sense:

> I've baked you a cake.
>
> I've dreamed you a cake.

It is something a child might say, and when used by adults it is a kind of metaphoric wordplay.

> I am not a king but I can dream you a castle.

There the verb "dream" is being used like the verb "wish".

P.S. Once you depart from a sentence pattern that makes clear the nature of the metaphoric use, things become unmoored, and then there's really no telling what is meant. What it means to dream someone a sin or to dream them a lie is anybody's guess.